# Numpy arrays means

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array in numpy with values like these:

```
array([ 22.1,  10.4,   9.3,  18.5,  12.9,   7.2,  11.8,  13.2,   4.8,
        10.6,   8.6,  17.4,   9.2,   9.7,  19. ,  22.4,  12.5,  24.4,
        11.3,  14.6,  18. ,  12.5,   5.6,  15.5,   9.7,  12. ,  15. ])
```

How can I replace all of the values in array on the mean of this array (the same mean for the whole array instead all of the values)?

Comment: What you've tried and what's the problem with your code and what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this?:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 22.1,  10.4,   9.3,  18.5,  12.9,   7.2,  11.8,  13.2,   4.8,
               10.6,   8.6,  17.4,   9.2,   9.7,  19. ,  22.4,  12.5,  24.4,
               11.3,  14.6,  18. ,  12.5,   5.6,  15.5,   9.7,  12. ,  15. ])

a[:] = np.mean(a)
print a
```

This gives:

```
[ 13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
  13.26666667  13.26666667]
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [np.place()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.place.html)

```
arr = np.array([ 22.1,  10.4,   9.3,  18.5,  12.9,   7.2,  11.8,  13.2,   4.8,
        10.6,   8.6,  17.4,   9.2,   9.7,  19. ,  22.4,  12.5,  24.4,
        11.3,  14.6,  18. ,  12.5,   5.6,  15.5,   9.7,  12. ,  15. ])

np.place(arr, arr, np.mean(arr))

print(arr)
    [ 13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
      13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
      13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
      13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
      13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667  13.26666667
      13.26666667  13.26666667]
```

Comment: -1 because it doesn't do exactly what you imply it does. If any of the values would be falsy (e.g. 0), they would not be replaced by that mean.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien Yep, my bad.